# Make (post) query a clickable link

Tags: wp-query

```
<?php 
query_posts( 
    array( 
        'showposts'             => $number, 
        'nopaging'              => 0, 
        'download_category'     => $term->name, 
        'orderby'               => 'meta_value_num',  
        'meta_key'              => 'post_views_count', 
        'order'                 => 'DESC', 
        'post_type'             => array( 'download' ), 
        'post_status'           => 'publish'
    ) 
); 

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
```

What this query does is sorting the page with the most views.

Now what I want to do is make this into a clickable link, like: "Most Views". Then, when you click on Most views link, the page will sort based on the most views.

Edit:

I should indeed have provided more information regarding this question:
We use a custom music template together with Easy Digital Downloads. 
http://www.dl-sounds.com

As you can see there's a widget with "Most Popular".  The code I provided comes from this widget. In the middle there's this box with "Newest Audio Files".  In this box I want to add a link so it will be possible for visitors to sort the audio by most views.

To be exact, I want to add a link in the sorting bar (Browse | Type | Tags)
The sorting bar is a php file.

I already did some testing with categories. I changed this  query with the query above in the category php.

```
<?php /* Genre Query */ query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'download', 'posts_per_page' =>'100000', 'download_category' => $term->name ) );while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

This is working fine. If I then browse the categories it is sorted by most views automatically. (on test site)

Comment: Well the question you asked is pretty abstract. I mean clicking and sorting is way too far from your given code domain. OK ? Share what you've tried till now to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a query string to your URL and then alter the query if that string is set. What I'm going to do is to use `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query.

```
function sort_by_views($query) {
    if ( 
        !is_admin() && 
        $query->is_main_query() &&
        $query->is_home() &&
        isset( $_REQUEST['sort_by_views'] ) 
    ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'download');
        $query->set( 'post_status', 'publish' );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $number );
        $query->set( 'nopaging', false );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'post_views_count' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sort_by_views' );
```

Now, if you navigate to `http://example.com/?sort_by_views=blabla`, your posts will be ordered by the views count.

This example works for main query on the homepage, but you can change the conditionals to meet any condition, based on your needs.

### One important note

Do not use `query_posts`. Use `WP_Query` instead. Using `query_posts` will alter the main query's data, which can mess with your content.

Answer (score 0):

For executing this query only on user's click action, you can use URL params.

In your template:

`$link = get_site_url() . '?most_views=' . (string) $param_value;`

Then in your function, you can use [`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) and do something like this:

```
function query_most_views() {
    if ( $param_value = get_query_var( 'most_views', false ) ) {
        // Your query based optionally on your $param_value...
    }
}
```